# TypeScript PrimeReact async Button onClick handler ESLint error

Tags: typescript, async-await, eslint, primereact

I try to export data from DataTable in PrimeReact. The Button onClick doesn't allow async callback as eslint told. How can I call this function properly?

```js
    const exportCSV = useCallback(async (_selectionOnly: boolean) => {
        //dt.current.exportCSV({ selectionOnly });
        try {
            const result = await fetch("/api/admin/crud/channels");
            const data: ChannelValue[] = await result.json() as ChannelValue[];
            const csv = convertToCSV(data);
            downloadCsvFile(csv, "download.csv");
        } catch (e: unknown) {
            show(toast, "error", "Please check is the powermeter-api runing.");
        }
    }, []);

    const header = (
        <>
            <div className="grid cols-2 justify-content-end w-ull">
                <div className="flex justify-content-end w-6 ">
                    <h2>Channels</h2>
                </div>
                <div className="flex align-items-center justify-content-end gap-2 end w-6 ">
                    <Button
                        type="button"
                        icon="pi pi-file"
                        rounded
// problem ===>         onClick={() => exportCSV(false)}
                        data-pr-tooltip="CSV"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
```

ESLint error: "Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises"

Please help me find right way to this.

Comment: You're calling the function immediately, during rendering. Did you mean `onClick={() => exportCSV(false)}`?

Comment: yesssssss, sure. I get eslint "Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises". I edited question, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises"

This error is happening because `onClick` expects a function that returns `void`, but your function returns `Promise<void>`. That's fine as far as typescript is concerned, but the no-misused-promises lint rule is stricter. You can fix the code by explicitly setting the return type to `void`:

```
onClick={(): void => exportCSV(false)}
```

Or:

```
const exportCSV = useCallback(async (_selectionOnly: boolean): void => {
  // ...
}, []);
```

Alternatively, if you feel this lint rule is too strict, you can disable it. To disable just this part of no-misused-promises, add this to your `.eslintrc` file:

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
  "error",
  {
    checksConditionals: true,
    checksSpreads: true,
    checksVoidReturn: false,
  },
],
```

To disable all parts of the rule:

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": "off"
```

[Documentation for this rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-misused-promises/)

Comment: If I put void to return type, this error occured: Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void'. So I turned off the rule on line by eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises.